# How to best extract attribute values and element values with LINQ and C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Before i start this is my first post, so if there is something i have done wrong or not done please tell me and i'll edit my post

I have a document which is formated as follows.

```
<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>
    <EventData>
        <Data Name='SubjectUserSid'>S-1-0-0</Data>
        <Data Name='SubjectUserName'>MACHINE$</Data>
        <Data Name='SubjectDomainName'>DOMAIN</Data>
        <Data Name='SubjectLogonId'>0x0</Data>
        <Data Name='TargetUserSid'>S-1-0-0</Data>
        <Data Name='TargetUserName'>username</Data>
        <Data Name='TargetDomainName'>TDname</Data>
        <Data Name='Status'>0x0</Data>
        <Data Name='FailureReason'>%%2313</Data>
        <Data Name='SubStatus'>0x0</Data>
        <Data Name='LogonType'>10</Data>
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

I have a little problem comming up with something that can extract the values from the XML (both the attribute values and the corresponding element values). Do i need a statement for each of the attribute or can i return a list and just loop over the values?

EDIT: The values needs to be extracted so i can send them to a database. I would like to try using LINQ for this, but Xpath might work aswell

EDIT2: Thank you for three good answers, i don't have the req. reputation to upvote answers yet and i need to get to my dev machine before testing, but this really looks what im looking for :)

Comment: Have you tried using xsd.exe to generate c# classes for this XML?  It can generate strongly typed classes that you can use to deserialize the XML into (linq not necessary)

Comment: There are various ways of parsing xml files: using DataSet, XmlSerializer, XPathDocument, XmlDocument, XDocument and XmlTextReader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood, you need to access properties and values as examples to parse xml.

> Do i need a statement for each of the attribute or can i return a list
>   and just loop over the values?

no you don't. Use next code as an example to parse xml:

```
//str contains your xml
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(str);
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event";

foreach (var node in xml.Descendants(ns + "Data"))
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Name: " + (string)node.Attribute("Name") + "; "+
                       "Value: " + node.Value);
}
```

will print:

```
Name: SubjectUserSid; Value: S-1-0-0
Name: SubjectUserName; Value: MACHINE$
Name: SubjectDomainName; Value: DOMAIN
Name: SubjectLogonId; Value: 0x0
Name: TargetUserSid; Value: S-1-0-0
Name: TargetUserName; Value: username
Name: TargetDomainName; Value: TDname
Name: Status; Value: 0x0
Name: FailureReason; Value: %%2313
Name: SubStatus; Value: 0x0
Name: LogonType; Value: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event";
var document = XDocument.Parse(
    "<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>" +
    "<EventData>" +
    "    <Data Name='SubjectUserSid'>S-1-0-0</Data>" +
    "    <Data Name='SubjectUserName'>MACHINE$</Data>" +
    "    <Data Name='SubjectDomainName'>DOMAIN</Data>" +
    "    <Data Name='SubjectLogonId'>0x0</Data>" +
    "    <Data Name='TargetUserSid'>S-1-0-0</Data>" +
    "    <Data Name='TargetUserName'>username</Data>" +
    "    <Data Name='TargetDomainName'>TDname</Data>" +
    "    <Data Name='Status'>0x0</Data>" +
    "    <Data Name='FailureReason'>%%2313</Data>" +
    "    <Data Name='SubStatus'>0x0</Data>" +
    "    <Data Name='LogonType'>10</Data>" +
    "</EventData>" +
    "</Event>");

var q = from element in document.Root.Element(ns + "EventData").Elements(ns + "Data")
        select new
        {
            Name = element.Attribute("Name").Value,
            Value = element.Value
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the attributes of each element:

```
var attributes = from n in xml.Descendants("Data")
                        select n.Attributes("Name").Select(s => s.Value);
```

To get the data of each element:

```
var data = from n in xml.Descendants("EventData")
                        select n.Elements("Data").Select(s => s.Value);
```

Or in one single query: -

```
var nodes = from n in xml.Descendants("EventData").Elements("Data")
                        select new
                        {
                            Data = n.Value,
                            Attribute = n.Attribute("Name").Value
                        };
```