# Linq to xml to read windows event log xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to read xml from EventLogRecord.ToXml() and print output in a "friendly" way, like in Windows Event Viewer. Input:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP" Guid="{E23B33B0-C8C9-472C-A5F9-F2BDFEA0F156}" EventSourceName="Software Protection Platform Service" />
  <EventID Qualifiers="16384">8230</EventID>
  <Version>0</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Task>0</Task>
  <Opcode>0</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-07-12T07:46:16.000000000Z" />
  <EventRecordID>11381</EventRecordID>
  <Correlation />
  <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
  <Channel>Application</Channel>
  <Computer>test</Computer>
  <Security />
</System>
<EventData>
  <Data>Security-SPP-Action-StateData </Data>
</EventData>
```

Output:

```
System
Provider
  [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP
  [ Guid]  {E23B33B0-C8C9-472C-A5F9-F2BDFEA0F156}
  [ EventSourceName]  Software Protection Platform Service
EventID 8230
  [ Qualifiers]  16384
Version 0
Level 4
Task 0
Opcode 0
Keywords 0x80000000000000
TimeCreated
  [ SystemTime]  2013-07-12T07:46:16.000000000Z
EventRecordID 11381
Correlation
Execution
  [ ProcessID]  0
  [ ThreadID]  0
Channel Application
Computer test
Security
EventData
    Security-SPP-Action-StateData
```

I know that I can use XmlTextReader and do some formatting after, like

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    switch (reader.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
            Console.Write(reader.Name);
            while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute()) // Read the attributes.
                Console.WriteLine(reader.Name + " " + reader.Value + " ");
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
            Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
            break;
    }
}
```

But is there a simpler way with Linq to XML to achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to best extract attribute values and element values with LINQ and C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878593/how-to-best-extract-attribute-values-and-element-values-with-linq-and-c-sharp)

Comment: @spender Thanks! It really is a duplicate.